# C# VSTO Namespace error when setting meta property of Word document

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, sharepoint-2013

I have a Sharepoint (2013) document library with a custom content type. The template for the content type is a VSTO Word document which executes some code when it's opened.
After the code is executed, a meta property of the document is changed.

Everything works fine, except on one person's computer. When the meta property is set he gets an error message about an undeclared namespace prefix:

```
Reference to undeclared namespace prefix ns3
```

This person still works in Windows 2007 and Office 2013 for...reasons. I suspect it has something to do with this, but I'm not sure. Maybe the underlying xml format of the Word document is different in 2013 as opposed to 2016 or something, I don't know.

My code looks roughly like this:

```
private void ThisDocument_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Core.MetaProperties oMetaProperties;
    oMetaProperties = (Office.MetaProperties)this.ContentTypeProperties;

    // Execute some code.

    oMetaProperties["Employee"].Value = sEmployeeListID; // This line produces the error.
}
```

For anyone familiar with Sharepoint, the column 'Employee' in the document library is of the type 'Sparqube Lookup Classic'. So not standard Sharepoint functionality.

Can anyone help me figure out what the cause of the problem is and how to fix it? Is it possible to explicitly set the namespace in code?